# F1026 File not found: 'Ucommon.dcu'

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i create simple delphi program i use 
MTable when make debug this error appear to me 
and flag for m_table in

> [DCC Error] Data.pas(7): F1026 File not found: 'Ucommon.dcu'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the unit named `Data` uses another unit named `Ucommon` and that the compiler cannot locate either a .pas source file, or a .dcu compiled unit for `Ucommon`.

You need to make sure that the compiler has access to `Ucommon`. Typically that means either:

1. Adding `Ucommon.pas` to the project, or
2. Adding the directory containing `Ucommon.pas` to the project's search path.

Comment: how can add ucommon.pas to my project?

Comment: On the Project menu select Add.

Comment: i mean where Ucommon.pas get from  ?

Comment: My crystal ball is not working today. Seriously though, it's your code not mine. I can't tell you where you put your code.

Comment: I Not Use file such AS Ucommon.pas :) ..I'm Beginner

Comment: Go to a Cmd prompt at the root of your Delphi drive & type 'dir ucommon.* /s [Return]'.  Does that display UCommon.Dcu or UCommon.Pas?

Comment: Since you are a beginner, you should tackle something more in keeping with your level of expertise. Trying to use third party code and resolve all of its dependencies is too hard for you. I  think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: @user3420275 `uCommon.pas` is not a common unit in Delphi. You got this unit from somewhere else, or perhaps you got `data.pas` from somewhere else but not the `uCommon.pas` unit.

Comment: To see if you really have the file somewhere, try a tool like [Everything](http://www-voidtools.com). With this, search your hard drive for a file `ucommon.*` and see if you have the `ucommon.pas` or `ucommon.dcu` file.